# D3 force layout - legend interactivity on/off

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force layout with a legend, and I’ve appended checkboxes to each role in the legend. 
I’m trying to follow this example(https://jsfiddle.net/zhanghuancs/cuYu8/) and add interactivity to the legend, but when I uncheck any of the checkboxes, all the links disappear instead of the links and nodes related to the role.
I’m creating the legend using this loop,

```
var col = color(d.group);
                   // adding code to display legend
                  // as nodes are filled
                  if(!(d.role in roles)){
                      legend.append("li")
                            .html(d.role)
                            .style("color", col)
                            //add checkbox
                            .append("input")
                            .attr("type", "checkbox")
                            .attr("id", function (d){
                                return "chk_" + d;
                            })
                            //check box
                            .property("checked", true)
                            .on("click", function (d){
                                //click event
                                var visibility = this.checked? "visible" : "hidden";
                                filterLegend(d,visibility);
                            })

                        roles[d.role] = true;
                    }

                  return col; })
```

Here’s a fiddle of my graph (https://jsfiddle.net/gbhrea/077mb7o1/1/), using a lot of data so just used a small sample for the fiddle. (graph won’t show on fiddle but will keep the link anyways so that full code can be seen)

Here is the code for changing visibility

```
function filterLegend(aType, aVisibility){
                    //change vis of link
                    link.style("visibility", function (o) {
            var lOriginalVisibility = $(this).css("visibility");
            return o.type === aType ? aVisibility : lOriginalVisibility;
        });
                //change vis of node
                //if links of node invisible, node should be too
                node.style("visibility", function (o, i) {
                    var lHideNode = true;
                    link.each(function (d, i) {
                        if (d.source === o || d.target === o) {
                            if ($(this).css("visibility") === "visible") {
                        lHideNode = false;

                            }
                        }
                    })
                });

              } //end filter
```

To be clear, what I want to achieve is - When I uncheck a role, e.g Actor, all nodes and links disappear. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I've made the changes to implement what I think you want [here](https://jsfiddle.net/077mb7o1/3/) -- I'm not entirely sure as the code was doing something completely different to what you're describing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code. First, you're not binding any data to the legend elements so `.on("click", function (d) { })` won't work because `d` isn't defined there. You do have `d.role` there though, so that's what you should use to pass on to functions.

Similarly, your `filterLegend()` function references undefined things (`.type`) -- this is why everything disappears at the moment. You're passing in something undefined and comparing it to something undefined, which gives `true`. Furthermore, links don't have the node information directly, but under `.source` and `.target`, so you need to compare to `.source.role` and `.target.role`.

For the nodes on the other hand, it's much easier than what your current code is trying to do -- there's no need to iterate over the links. You can use the code you have for the links here, except for comparing to the existing `.role` attribute instead of the non-existing `.type`.

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/077mb7o1/3/).